# Django having one to one and many to many rel in the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models

We want to having many to many and one to one relationship within the same model. Let me give an example.

```
class Definition(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    container_specific_defn = models.OneToOneField(Definition, null=True, blank=True)
    definitions = models.ManyToManyField(Definition)
```

As you can see a `Container` model have both 1to1 and m2m rel with `Definition` model. ie. I want `Container` can have any number of definitions but the defn which we are goinig to be added to `definitions` set should not be added to any container's `container_specific_defn` field.

But the above model design allows a `defn` which was assigned to one contaioner's `container_specific_defn` field to be added to another container's `definitions` set.

```
container_specific_defn = Definition.objects.create(value='container_specific')
global_defn = Definition.objects.create(value='global')

c1 = Container.objects.create(name='c1', container_specific_defn=container_specific_defn)
c2 = Container.objects.create(name='c2')
c2.definitions.add(container_specific_defn)
c2.save()
# [container_specific_defn]
```

Do I need to change the model design?

Comment: I don't think you need to change model design, instead you can put some validations/restrictions so that `container_specific_defn` can't be added to `definitions`

Comment: hm ok. I'm thinking about m2m_changed signal.

Comment: I haven't used it before, but I think you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing definitively wrong with your model design, but I would probably model this differently: using a through table with a "specific" field.

```
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    definitions = models.ManyToManyField(Definition, through="ContainerDefinition")

class ContainerDefinition(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    definition = models.ForeignKey(Definition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    specific = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: If we set `specific` as `True`, it would act as one to one relationship but I want to do the restriction at db level. Does unique together container, definition pks would help?